# Check if both dates are within the same month python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
df= {
    "Date_one": ["05-02-2023", "04-12-2023", "02-23-2023", "01-01-2023", "10-11-2023"],
    "Date_two": ["05-22-2023", "06-02-2023", "05-22-2023", "01-22-2023", "10-23-2023"],
}
```

| Date_one | Date_two |
| --- | --- |
| 05-02-2023 | 05-22-2023 |
| 04-12-2023 | 06-02-2023 |
| 02-23-2023 | 05-22-2023 |
| 01-01-2023 | 01-22-2023 |
| 10-11-2023 | 10-23-2023 |

I need to check if both dates are within the same month, like in the first and last row.

What would be the best way to obtain this result?

| Date_one | Date_two | Str_yes or not |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05-02-2023 | 05-22-2023 | Yes,is paid |
| 04-12-2023 | 06-02-2023 | No pay |
| 02-23-2023 | 05-22-2023 | No pay |
| 01-01-2023 | 02-22-2023 | No pay |
| 10-11-2023 | 10-23-2023 | Yes,is paid |

I had thought of assigning within another column the last day of the month with respect to the first column.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. This is a Q&A site, so what's the question? Like, what do you need help with exactly? To start, do you know [how to access the month](//pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html) individually? Are these data actually dates or just strings? Please make a [reproducible pandas example](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: + your I/O don't match. Also, what should be the result for `01-15-2022` Vs. `01-20-2023` ?

Comment: @Timeless Oh yeah, `01-22-2023` != `02-22-2023`

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Extracting just Month and Year separately from Pandas Datetime column](/q/25146121/4518341)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare `.dt.month` attribute between `datetime` objects (preliminary obtaining them by applying [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)):

```
df['Pay_status'] = np.where(df['Date_one'].dt.month == df['Date_two'].dt.month,
                            'Yes, is paid', 'No pay')
```

```
    Date_one   Date_two    Pay_status
0 2023-05-02 2023-05-22  Yes, is paid
1 2023-04-12 2023-06-02        No pay
2 2023-02-23 2023-05-22        No pay
3 2023-01-01 2023-01-22  Yes, is paid
4 2023-10-11 2023-10-23  Yes, is paid
```

Comment: It helped me a lot but using the default date of 01-01-1970, it results in 'yes, is paid'.

Answer (score 0):

you should first make sure the Date columns are of the type datetime. For example, if you are reading the table from a csv file you can do:

```
data = pd.read_csv('location.csv', parse_dates=['Date_one', 'Date_two'])
```

or convert them afterwards:

```
data['Date_one'] = pd.to_datetime(data.Date_one)
```

then you can do simply:

```
data['paid_same_month'] = (data.Date_one.dt.month == data.Date_two.dt.month).map(
    {True: 'Yes', False: 'No'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming df is your dataframe and pandas is imported as pd:

```
df['output'] = (pd.to_datetime(df.Date_one).dt.month == pd.to_datetime(df.Date_two).dt.month).replace({True:'yes',False:'no'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like that:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Date_one": ["05-02-2023", "04-12-2023", "02-23-2023", "01-01-2023", "10-11-2023"],
    "Date_two": ["05-22-2023", "06-02-2023", "05-22-2023", "01-22-2023", "10-23-2023"],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert date columns into DateTime objects with the specified format
df["Date_one"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date_one"], format="%m-%d-%Y")
df["Date_two"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date_two"], format="%m-%d-%Y")

# Extract months from date columns
df["Month_Date_one"] = df["Date_one"].dt.month
df["Month_Date_two"] = df["Date_two"].dt.month

# Adds a Boolean column to check if months are equal
df["Month_Equal"] = df["Month_Date_one"] == df["Month_Date_two"]
df["Month_Equal"] = df["Month_Equal"].map({True: "Yes, is paid", False: "No pay"})

print(df)
```